# How to add to an jsx/html tag inside a javascript function (reactJS)

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs, jsx

I'm trying to insert an iframe tag inside a javascript function because I didn't want it to render as soon as the page loaded, I want it to render as makePlaylist function is called. This jquery code is wrong and I'm not sure what would work.

```
function makePlaylist(){
      $('fav_Playlist').html('<iframe title="user_playlist" src="${https://open.spotify.com/embed/playlist/ +this.state.real_id}"></iframe>');

}


render(){
    return (
        window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', (event) => { 
            this.makePlaylist(); //Have tracks load immediately             
        }),
         <div className="fav_Playlist">

         </div>
    );
}
```

This is just part of my code so disregard lack of other code

Answer (score 0):

Try now: Change the iframe URL with your spotify URL

```
let Component = React.createClass({
  iframe: function () {
    return {
      __html: this.props.iframe
    }
  },

  render: function() {
    return (
      <div>
        <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML = { this.iframe() } />
      </div>
    );
  }
});

let iframe = '<iframe width="420" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/tgbNymZ7vqY"></iframe>'; 

ReactDOM.render(
  <Component iframe={iframe} />,
  document.getElementById('iframe_load_here')
);
```

Working Iframe Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/usmanmunir/hwg6e70m/14/

Comment: Doesn't do anything, passing the Id doesnt change much, I actually have real_id as a state variable in the constructor so putting that as a param doesn't change much

Comment: Updated my answer. I Was not sure how are you calling the function. Give it a shot

Comment: your iframe isn't loading anything

Comment: You are using reactJs with Jquery. Its not ideal. Hence why it will not render the iframe. See the updated answer

Comment: But how can I make this code render inside the makePlaylist function, I dont want it to render as the page loads

Comment: When do you want it to render ? onclick ? after sometime ? Please specify in details what are the requirements in detail

Comment: I actually render it as the page loads as you can see, but I want the function makePlaylist to render it because in my actual code the songs are being added in that function, so if it's rendered before that function, it'll have a split second where there are 0 songs on the iframe